Can't the electric current returning from the neutral end of the electrical cables be used again?
I am someone who has little knowledge about electricity, but I have something I am curious about. I could not find the answer by searching on the internet.
If the electric current comes from the phase terminal and is used in the device, and the same current returns to the electrical source from the neutral terminal, can't a system that will be installed in the electrical source reuse the current coming from this neutral terminal? Why does this current have to be given to the ground?

The current "returning to the source from the neutral" is not "given to the ground" at all.

electric current moves at about one mile per hour and changes direction 50 or 60 times per second most of it stays indie the device and what escapes is reused,  I think you need to learn about potential. (also called voltage)

I have often wondered why the electric company charges me for electrons I use, considering they get them back again.

@MichaelHarvey Because they get them back all tired and need to refresh them by giving them a ride on a 3000rpm merry-go-round. (Yes, I know there are transformers in the way, but can't come up with a nice analogy for those.)

@MichaelHarvey Can't complain, unlike the water company they don't charge me to take the dirty electrons away when i'm done with them, even if I didn't actually return them and used them to fill my swimming pool instead...

There's an easy to understand comparable case (see NOTE1): Water above the dam falls down through a pipe and rotates a turbine. Why do we let the water go away? Why do we not let it rotate another turbine because the water still is in our hands just below the dam and first turbine?
The 2nd turbine would be useless if there's no second drop above it. Nothing generates the needed pressure to make the turbine to rotate. But generally the river is tilted a little, so the water falls a little and for that reason it can flow away.
In the same way the electric charge passing the load has already used its possibility to fall down in the electric field generated by the electricity source. It does not flow away, but it's pulled through the neutral wire back the electricity source. It's a part of the metal and other materials and it's needed to keep the materials together. If it somehow flew off the circuit (for example to the ground or empty space) the circuit would get soon oppositely charged and the charge losses would be stopped by the caused electric field.
ADDED after comment

you said that the electric charge is already used. Do you claim that
the electrons coming from the phase end to the electronic device
cannot create energy again after returning to the source from the
neutral end or that they can create less energy? If we store the
current coming from the neutral wire somewhere, can't we use it with
another electrical potential energy later?

I said the charge which comes to the neutral wire and returns to the source has  used the possibility to fall in the electric field. That's like water which has already fallen down cannot fall more without a new waterfall.
The charge can well be reused by the source if some energizing process (=chemical processes in a battery, electric fields generated by a generator) lift it back up in the electric potential like sun lifts water from the sea back to mountains.
Actually only recycled charge is available, because the electrons are a part of the material in the circuit, so re-energizing the same charge again is the only way how the sources of continuous electric power can work in circuits. You cannot reduce nor increase the amount of the electrons substantially from the amount the material contains naturally. It's possible by generating somehow extreme electric fields or by breaking the material to separate particles. In circuits electrons simply go back to the source and that keeps the charge in the source in its natural balance without any extra effort.
A recommendation: Study the basics of the electricity from schoolbooks. Remember that you may have already built your own thinking models of electricity which can clash badly with science and should be broken or they prevent you to learn the schoolbook content which hopefully is based on science.
Beware YouTube videos which demonstrate electricity. Their quality and intentions vary wildly. Only a person who has already built a solid on science (not on other YouTube videos or beliefs or opinions) based knowledge of the subject can properly make a difference between facts and rubbish.
NOTE1: This is actually suggested in a comment by Bart van Heukelom. Comparable means analogy. The same mathematical equations describe 2 totally different physical phenomenons. In this case water mass has the the same place in gravitation force & potential energy equations as charge has in the equations of force and potential energy for electric fields.
The analogy is not valid for all nuances of electricity; for example we have plus and minus charges, but we do not have any substantial piece of matter which has negative mass and nothing like magnetism has been observed around moving masses. I do not claim they are non-existent in advanced theories of nuclear particles or galaxy magnitude masses.

Love it. The way the question was asked, the rest of the answers will be useless to the OP.

Thank you for this answer. But you said that the electric charge is already used. Do you claim that the electrons coming from the phase end to the electronic device cannot create energy again after returning to the source from the neutral end or that they can create less energy? If we store the current coming from the neutral wire somewhere, can't we use it with another electrical potential energy later?

@Ahmet the answer has now more.

Thanks again. I just wanted to clarify the point I made in my original question. Yes, I understood your answer more clearly with the help of a few YouTube videos.

You might say the charge of the electrons is equivalent to the mass of the water molecules. It's what the voltage / gravity "grabs on" to pull it through the load, but it remains in the particle.

That's a detail of the analogy, so your refinement is perfectly valid.

Actually, there are no mobile "plus charge" particles (at least in solids like copper/aluminium wiring or semiconductors), any plus charges are electron holes. And those work exactly like air bubbles in water, they will also flow upwards while the water (electrons) go the opposite way. Magnetism is harder indeed.

A variant on this: imagine a bicycle chain. Individual chain links go out and come back. You could say they are "reused". But it's not the links themselves that are the energy, it's the force being applied to move them. Electrons in this analogy are like the chain links, they transfer energy but they are not themselves used up.

@TooTea Alpha particles and protons have positive charge because they are fully ionized helium and hydrogen atoms. Nuclear physicists produce high speed alpha particle and proton beams for their experiments. Nuclear reactions, stars and the sun generate them, too. Those beams - maybe fortunately - turn to ordinary helium and hydrogen after moving few centimeters in the air or less than a millimeter in solids. I wouldn't say air bubbles have negative mass. They rise in the water because the hydrostatic pressure difference between below the bubble and above the bubble wins the weight of the air.

But the current does not return to ground.
You should perhaps consider the mains wires (live and neutral) like a bicycle chain, drive belt in car engine, or closed loop water circulation heating system.
You have one thing that delivers power to everything connected to it, and like an electric circuit, the chain or belt needs to be a closed loop to deliver power, and same amount of water must flow from pump into radiator that exits the radiator.
So an AC generator is like a pump for water or pedals for the chain - the generator moves electrons around in a wire so they can do work at the remote end of wires.

Yes, a bicycle chain is a brilliant analogy! The other analogies are good too. This should be the accepted answer. It's simple, concise, and easy to understand.

A DC supply (such as a battery, or phone charger) can be thought of as driving the chain continually in one direction; whilst an AC supply (such as mains power) moves it repeatedly forward and back, forward and back.

With a chain, you could add another wheel to turn on the same chain, though. But with mechanics, it's probably more intuitive to figure out that would then mean more work would need to be done at the source to have them both turn at the same rate. In a same way, adding another load in the electrical "chain" can be one, but would split the voltage and power over the two loads.

And yes, you can use the current again -- the generator just needs to work harder to push the chain of electrons around the circuit.

We'll examine your idea with a simple DC circuit. Here we'll use the DC negative as "neutral".

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In Figure 1a you can see that the 12 V battery feeds one lamp. Current is 0.12 A and the voltage across the lamp is 12 V. Since P = VI, the power dissipated in the lamp is 0.12 × 12 = 1.44 W.
In Figure 1b you we have added a second lamp on the "neutral". This has doubled the resistance of the circuit so the current has fallen to 0.06 A. Additionally, each lamp only gets half the voltage, 6 V each. Again, using P = VI, the power dissipated in each lamp is 0.06 × 6 = 0.36 W.
In your "free energy" scheme each lamp will be running at 1/4 power.

Why does this current have to be given to the ground?

It isn't "given to the ground". It is returned to the voltage source - the local transformer in most AC situations or the battery in my example. The ground connection just "neutralises" that wire so that fuses aren't required in it and so that the live wire is referenced to ground.

Because the difference in energy between the line and neutral terminals is what transfers energy to the device being powered. You can't even inductively couple off of the current in the neutral line "for free" since it would induce a counter-voltage and raise the potential of "0V" that the rest of your equipment sees. The neutral line that goes into your house is (at least in the US) bonded to earth ground at your distribution panel so there is no readily available lower potential available.

It's AC, so "lower" is not really a thing either.  You certainly can have a larger potential difference, for example by going between phases instead of from one phase to neutral (ground).


Can't the electric current returning from the neutral end of the
electrical cables be used again?

To electrically power a load you need both voltage and current to be present. The returning current in your question has an effective voltage of zero volts hence, that current does not qualify.

In fact the current does recirculate in a circuit, often not passing through ground on the way.  For example, the secondary circuit of an isolating transformer permits no flow to ground (not even indirectly, via neutral/common).
The thing to focus on is that by the time the current returns, it has given up its energy.  You have to bring it back to a power source in order to raise its voltage, then it carries energy again.

A misleading and unclear answer. It is more correct to say the potential energy is lost. It is like lowering a heavy weight to the ground. The potential energy of the weight has been expended.

@SodAlmighty: That's ridiculous.  While factually correct that the energy falls into the category of "potential energy", OP isn't interested in differentiating potential, kinetic, thermal energies.  They simply need to focus on the difference between current/charge and power/energy.  Also, your comment is far more incorrect.  Potential energy has not been "lost", it has been conserved (into useful work, waste heat, or some other energy storage).

It's probably better to think of an AC system as a metal rod.

The hot side is pushing and pulling this rod.
Something like a crank arm in the middle is extracting the energy from the moving rod; the device you're powering.
The end of the rod has a lubricated sleeve for the rod to go in and out of smoothly; the neutral side.

As you push the rod, the device in the middle is extracting the energy right away. Once you reach the end of the stroke, that energy is gone. Now you need to move the rod back, but it's still the hot side doing this work. Just to make good use of the time, you extract energy from the hot side in this cycle as well, but make no mistake, there's no excess energy left to be extracted from the neutral side (lubricated sleeve).
Perhaps you're thinking that we could install a spring in the lubricated sleeve to store some energy and extract it back on the "pull" cycle. Sure, you could, but first you have to put the energy into the spring. That's extra energy you have to put into the system on the push stroke to get it back on the pull stroke. While possible from an electrical perspective, you're not actually gaining any efficiency. If anything, you'll lose efficiency due to friction/resistance.
So instead, we just extract exactly how much we want on the push stroke and on the pull stroke. There's never any energy left over in the neutral line.

Not wrong; but nowhere near as clear as the bicycle chain analogy.

@SodAlmighty The whole reason to avoid the bicycle analogy is exactly as you said. A/C doesn't act like a floppy chain running in one direction. If the chain was under full tension so it could pull in both directions that would work, but I'm sure there's not many actual applications that do that.

Personally, I don't find it particularly mentally taxing to imagine a taut chain that can drive work in both directions. And I feel that the ease with which the analogy can be understood is valuable.

@SodAlmighty Well you're not alone apparently. The masses say you're right. I've probably spent too much time thinking about mechanics lately.

@SodAlmighty The bicycle chain analogy is great, but breaks down when talking about AC because you don't need to pedal in both directions to get the transformer effect, you only need gearing.

No analogy is perfect.

I just stumbled across this and perhaps this will help. According to the laws of physics energy can not be created or destroyed it can only be converted or changed. If it is used in an incandescent light bulb,  say a 100 watt lamp. The lamp or bulb “uses” the power or electrical potential to convert the 100 watts to light and heat. the ratio is about 10% light and 90% heat. Once the potential is changed to another form of energy it can be changed again but the electrical potential is gone converted to heat and light.
Unlike a gas generator it is a 100% efficient conversion.
if those ratios are exact then 90 watts of heat and 10 watts of light would be converted from the 100 watts of electricity. In LED lighting you will find the advertised lumens per watt so you can quantify the amount of light. But incandescent lighting is so inefficient that you rarely see the light produced as lumens.
A gas generator for example would lose mechanical “potential“ due to friction and solar PV cells lose efficiency due to several factors and the most electrical potential for the solar panels is now around 25% efficiency. There is no such thing as a perpetual motion machine or free power created from nothing. It is always a converted source of energy like mechanical, heat, radiation etc. no free lunch in nature or physics. Plants store energy from the sun. We can in turn eat the plants and provide energy for our bodies or burn trees to stay warm. Almost all of the energy in our world comes from the sun. Oil is decaying plants from millions of years ago converted into oil. Oil is converted into gasoline and diesel etc and turned into mechanical, electrical and heat energy in our automobile. Gravity and the motion of our moon and planets also power the oceans, winds rivers etc. All of that energy can be converted into electricity and vice versa. Think of it as energy instead of electricity that might help. Cheers
